# Connection between two theorems on character values?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, finite-groups

In a recent arXiv preprint [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.5504), Dipendra Prasad has revisited a 1976 theorem of Kostant (Theorem 2 in the paper *On Macdonald's $\eta$-function formula, the Laplacian and generalized exponents*, Advances in Math. 20 (1976), no. 2, 179-212).   In the setting of a simply connected compact simple Lie group, the theorem says that any finite dimensional irreducible representation has character value $0, 1$. or $-1$ at the (lift of a) Coxeter element.  Here the group could equally well be a complex Lie group or algebraic group.  The Coxeter elements of the Weyl group lift to the normalizer of a maximal torus and yield a single conjugacy class in the Lie group.   (This and other foundational results from Kostant's 1959 paper are surveyed in a Bourbaki talk by [Koszul](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=SB_1958-1960__5__329_0).)

This reminds me of another 1976 theorem, proved in a different area of representation theory.   This was a Warwick collaboration by
J.A. Green, G.I. Lehrer, and G. Lusztig, *On the degrees of certain group characters*, Quart. J. Math. Oxford Ser. (2) 27 (1976), no. 105, 1-4.  They deal with the complex irreducible characters of the finite group $G$ of rational points of a reductive algebraic group over a finite field.   Under mild conditions the regular unipotent elements form a single conjugacy class, and the theorem states that any irreducible character takes value $0, 1,$, or $-1$ at such an element.

> Is there a natural connection between these theorems?  (For example, does one directly imply the other?)

A couple of specialists I've asked don't immediately recognize such a connection, and there may in fact be none.   However, the Coxeter elements are related to a class of regular semisimple elements in Kostant's theorem, while the Jacobson/Morozov lemma (valid for large enough prime characteristic) may provide a bridge between these and the regular unipotent elements.   Even though the two kinds of representations are not at all the same, they are related indirectly by reduction modulo $p$.   So it may be worth asking the question.

Comment: Just a brief added comment from the current AMS webpage, the news that Sandy Green has recently died at age 88.  See also the extensive biographical page at MacTutor http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~history/Biographies/Green_Sandy.html